# error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number[]' and '-1000'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am receiving the following error in my ng serve logs even though the function runs fine with no problems. This is going to become an issue though when I build for production. How do I fix this error?

```
uuidv4() {
    return ([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
      (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
    )
  }
```

In my service I calling it this.uuidv4() to generate a unique ID.

Comment: here `[1e7]+-1e3` why do you use a bracket here?

Comment: What is `[1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11` supposed to do? `[1e7]` is an array, `-1e3+...` is a number, and then you're calling `replace` which doesn't exist on arrays or numbers. Did you mean for this whole thing to be a string?

Comment: "even though the function runs fine with no problems" In what ways have you tried it? This shouldn't work in any way. Did you write this code yourself?

Comment: The code your posted really looks like it is build by someone who tried to be clever, and then minified the code by using automatic JS conversions. Converting it to valid typescript is not going to happen without major rewrites

Comment: TypeScript is warning you that adding a numeric array with a number is more likely to be a bug than intended code, even if it's [technically legal JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean). Change it to something less crazy (e.g., the string literal `"10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000"`) or use `as any` assertions to silence the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I understand what it's doing now. This code `[1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11` takes advantage of the [addition operator's](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) inherent type coercion. For example, `[]+0` returns `"0"` and `[1]-1` returns `"1-1"`. It works just fine in JavaScript, but TypeScript is warning you about it because this kind of code is *usually* the result of a typo or logical error.

So that expression is just a little bit of [code golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) for `"10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000"`. Just replace that expression with the result value in your code like so:

```
return "10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000".replace(/[018]/g, c =>
  (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16)
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!