# Object is possibly 'undefined' Error on Optional Chaining Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, boolean, optional-chaining

I have a response which I am accessing: `data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps?`. As you can guess, data, currentOrganization, and onboardingSteps might all be null. I want to assign a variable as follows:

`const hasSteps = data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps?.length > 0;`

I thought hasValue would evaluate to false if any of the fields were null or if there was less than 1 step. However, I get the TypeScript error: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

This is how I am currently getting around it:

```
const hasSteps =
  data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps != null &&
  data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps?.length > 0;
```

This feels unnecessarily verbose. Is there an alternative, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [optional chain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) will end up producing a value for `data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps?.length` which is presumably a `number` if everything in the chain is not `null` or `undefined`.... but if anything in the chain is nullish, then the output will be `undefined` itself.  You can't test `undefined > 0` without Typescript complaining about it.

So you should probably do something like the following:

```
const hasSteps = (data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps?.length ?? 0) > 0;
```

This is using [nullish coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) to produce `0` if the optional chain ends in `undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3sKGoC54BvAKHkQFcY4UMB5GAcyhQEsAvXV1AfkNPLlUAIySxgrFIwDKGEAAc0fYmUHkIIKRgAWhFBQC2wkDFXkAvqsvn4AH3gUUoAGaSQwEiRx4eAOjBUNPRMLBxcvL4iYjASUrIKSr4aWtrwAHzwAAwA3J7I6FjaUGjxivAAvPAAFN5QfgHUmsHMbJwY3Ch+UeKSMnKKfsmMOvA8PFkAlOlZ2UA)

Comment: Unfortunately though, if you stick this in an if statement, Typscript won't infer that data/currentOrganization/etc are defined, unlike the predecessor, data && data.currentOrganization, etc., which would then satisfy the null/undefined type checking, and allow you to access those properties in the if block. Any way to make that work with this strategy?

Comment: A comment section on an old question isn't a great place to do this, but: checking `x > 0` doesn't act as a type guard on `x`, but `typeof x === "number"` does, so you can write `if (typeof data?.currentOrganization?.onboardingSteps?.length === "number")` and then the compiler should allow you to access all the intermediate properties separately.  If you want to discuss further you might want to post your own question with a [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: `undefined > 0` is a valid expression yielding `false` on any JavaScript engine. It's unclear why it fails in TypeScript.

Comment: Looks like you want https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45543 .  Note that "it works in JS so it should work in TS" is not going to convince the TS team.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218 .  The argument would need to be more like "comparisons like `x > 0` where `x` might be `undefined` is widely used in idiomatic real-world JavaScript", along with supporting evidence.