# Optional chaining operator on for loop length

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, for-loop

I'm using Optional chaining operator which should solve this error, but in my loop allLinks.length i'm getting `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` (my code works fine, just want to get rid of this error.)
i can fix it like this but its not right way :
const allLinks : any = props.Data?.nodes;

any suggestion is appreciated.

what am I doing wrong here ?

```
  const allLinks = props.Data?.nodes;
      for (let i = 0; i < allLinks?.length; i++) {
        if (
          allLinks?.[i].source == currentCam.id 
        ) {
          dispatch(linkById(allLinks?.[i].id));
        }
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object is possibly 'undefined' Error on Optional Chaining Typescript](/q/66017941/90527)

Comment: By using optional chaining you're telling TS that the "Object is possibly 'undefined'" which is the warning it's giving you. [A possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017941/object-is-possibly-undefined-error-on-optional-chaining-typescript).

Comment: @Andy even without optional chaining its giving same warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it in correct way, Just a suggestion - You can use [`Nullish coalescing operator (??)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) along with [`Optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator.

```
const allLinks = props.Data?.nodes ?? []
```

It will provide a fallback value when dealing with `null` or `undefined` values.

Comment: @walee Done. Kindly do accept this answer if it helps you. So that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well facing same problem.