# Creating property inside constructor with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript code that works perfectly:

```js
class myController {
   constructor () {
      this.language = 'english'
   }
}
```

BUT when I try to do the same with `Typescript`

```js
export default class myController {
  constructor () {
    this.language = 'english'
  }
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> Property 'language' does not exist on type 'myController'.ts(2339)

Why exactly this happen when trying to create a property for `myController`?
What would be the right way to do so?

Comment: You need to declare a variable out of the constructor like `private language: string`.

Comment: Read about [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are trying to set a property which does not exist in the class as it says, declare it somewhere in the class before you try set it, i.e:

```
export default class myController {
  private language: string;
  constructor () {
    this.language = 'english'
  }
}
```

Comment: I maked the same response but I add a comment hahaha

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll upvote both. I thought as this could be done with `javascript` I would also be able to do it in `TS`. Thanks

Comment: "I thought as this could be done with javascript I would also be able to do it in TS" See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be declared as a Property on the type (typically before the constructor):

```
export default class myController {
  language: string;
  constructor () {
    this.language = 'english'
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html for more info

Comment: Just as a tip: It does not need to be above the constructor, all property declarations are called before the constructor no matter where in the class they are, having them above does make the most sense though