# TypeScript 4.6.4 is indicating that this code is not valid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nullable

How do I resolve this Typescript issue?

```typescript
const userData: {
      email: string;
      id: string;
      _token: string;
      _tokenExpirationDate: string;
    } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

[image]

Message from Console

> Error: src/app/auth/authservice.ts:56:20 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I added the // @ts-ignore
but WebStorm is complaining that there is an error.

Comment: And what do you expect to happen if the storage is empty?

Comment: Well if it's empty wouldn't userData be null then I return from the login method and the user is not authenticated

Comment: Yes, but TypeScript is of the opinion that `JSON.parse()` should be passed a string, not a `null`.  If you want to get something a little more type safe (but `JSON.parse()` returns `any` so it's never going to be safe by itself) then you should refactor so that you only pass a string, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w23VYN). If you just want to silence the error then you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBRLpN) and note that I corrected the annotated type to include `null`.   What do you want to see here?

Comment: @jcalz your idea is brilliant. Please post it so I can credit you with the solution

Comment: Stack Snippets are for HTML/CSS/JavaScript code. You added TypeScript in the HTML box. Click "Run code snippet" in that case does not illustrate anything interesting. Please use Stack Snippets for runnable code only. Otherwise, just use the regular code button, that looks like `{}`, after highlighting the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore the fact that `JSON.parse()`'s [call signature declaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/938a69a526166ca4e7880fa140fba432936f0fe3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1126) returns [the unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  I'll just assume that if `JSON.parse()` returns anything other than `null`, it will be a value of your expected object type.

---

It's possible that `localStorage.getItem("userData")` might be `null`, and TypeScript thinks that it's a mistake to call `JSON.parse(null)`, since generally the point of `JSON.parse()` is to parse strings that encode JSON values.  Parsing `null` is therefore a type error, even though JavaScript will not have a runtime error.  See [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218) for more information.

If you're trying to fix it to be more type safe, you should make sure only to pass a `string`.  Perhaps like this:

```
const retrievedValue = localStorage.getItem('userData');
const userData = retrievedValue ? JSON.parse(retrievedValue) as {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  _token: string;
  _tokenExpirationDate: string;
} : null;
```

This compiles without error, and now `userData` has the type `{email: string ... } | null`, where the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) with [the `null` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) reflects that `userData` might either be a valid object or `null`.

---

If you want to be expedient but a little less safe, you could just lie to the compiler about the local storage result and [*assert* that it is not `null` using the non-null assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-):

```
const userData: {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  _token: string;
  _tokenExpirationDate: string;
} | null = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')!);
```

Note that I added the `| null` manually there, since the compiler can't see that possibility anymore.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgMoD2kA7gBYgAuFIAZsgYUUvFcFCZIAThCbCAlhABuEACYA1TAFdkAXiQYq6DBSZVhIAOYQAdCaYBJJhDAAKAOTKoEYQBFmIBwEoA3NyI+ASFnVw8mECQNUXEpWUUVZAB+VAoAeQA5UzhhFzsYyRl5JQxVbyQQKDwAnlsQCQwALiRBSWAjfx4eCTlm1ol2zq6kAH19AGsIYD7YwZqiMapJ4ABRAA8YCUMmCX5wiBm2jpqAXyRm4GUMDH9uE-xuEmg4RCQAGWgoVg5qrqDBJChdyeZoEYZIOoNQ4DY7gnrQubgxbLBGw4bIqbrTbbXbAfaooZEM4AH2IVwwUVSmWyIFyEDsWh0egMxjMFmstkcQPCXm8AEJvA8iULiOBnuQkABZAwQb6cGpsZTAeA7fhIRhfWZGAAKwioMCgAB4ANIQtY2YByKr9doAPjsVAARgArZogYAATwANEhTH6YHqDc1jQBtAC63maTudSAkVVwSBD2tjwCQxrDqKQZzBwxiymEqejSAAZMWkAH9VBTEVhB67OMorakEwPTAIFQ2EhoyHxmGomoNAAiG1GQd+U4ioiK5Wq1MWACCyiY9Ds5Rzf34AO5IMBwHGwCotFTGhQ6SyOTyjMwzMMJnMYg59icLmBER8SCSKUHl2uY8J3U7Ow+Q1PQjl1Ss7G3CIfUHSEMEHGCegQpBBwxYBkNQiZMQ2LZmFxfYx3KPMCzJa5-yIYjUygkAJzufATiAA)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem IMO is to just do this:

```
const userData: {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  _token: string;
  _tokenExpirationDate: string;
} = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') ?? "null");
```

*Note the [nullish coalascing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) operator (`??`) requires typescript 3.7*

---

Now in the case that you want your type to reflect the possibility of being null (in case localStorage does not contain `'userData'`), then you probably want to use a union type with `null`:

```
const userData: {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  _token: string;
  _tokenExpirationDate: string;
} | null = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') ?? "null");
```

At this point, you might as well extract that `userData` type to an interface:

```
interface UserData {
  email: string;
  id: string;
  _token: string;
  _tokenExpirationDate: string;
}

const userData: UserData | null = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') ?? "null");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can directly assign empty string in case localstorage doesn't have assigned value

```
var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData') ?? '');
```