# How to call "new functionName()" with typescript

Tags: typescript

The following snippet is a valid JavaScript and I want to implement it in TypeScript.

Give this snippet:

```js
class A {
  val: number;
  constructor() {
    this.val = 1;
  }
}

class B {
  val: number;
  constructor() {
    this.val = 2;
  }
}

function autosense(what: string) {
  if (what === 'a') {
    return new A();
  } else {
    return new B();
  }
}

console.log(new autosense('a').val);
```

I get this error:

```
 error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.

23 console.log(new autosense('a').val);
```

I know `autosense` is a factory and the `new` keyword is useless. But I WANT to call it with `new autosense()` - there are no cons on doing this (the function is used as constructor to a temporary object that is not used actually).

How can I fix this typescript issue and make it accept a valid javascript code?

Comment: "I want to do this thing because there are no cons and because I want to" there's no pros either. Remove the `new` keyword and this behaves as you'd like, right?

Comment: "*there are no cons on doing this*" - except that it doesn't work with TS, that it is confusing to whoever reads the code, and that it is slow because it unnecessarily constructs an unused object?

Comment: TS challange - does ts do the same things js can do? Maybe the underline question is this one. (I removed the `new` kw if you are happy to know it, anyway I want to find a way to do it or I would like a ts guru that tell me that it is impossible)

Comment: "underline"?  ...EDIT oh, you must mean *underlying*

Comment: If that's the actual question then the answer is [intentionally *no*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean).  If you want to work around it you can always use type assertions or the like, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3E91w).  So, which one of these is your actual question (you should probably [edit] to make that clear), and what should we do to proceed here?

Comment: Yes, I meant "underlying"

I think the `asNewable` is the right answer -  I will study it, it generates this code `function asNewable(f) { return f; }`. Please post it as answer!

lol to those -1 to a clear question, go away if you are not interested to find a way to do it.

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon You can always use [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQG5hALmgOwFcBbAIwFMAnAbhTWAHs8IAXCg4Z+igCgEpFaaNMwAWASwgA6TCGgBeaAEYaQgL5J1SUJBgAhAUJm5CpSirqMWbDlz4Ghw8VJnzoAJnOp1mgGYE8HGKM0GAEnBBkTGTcAO4iYMy4VmJ4AOb8yEJiPtCx8czycgoA5GDFGYIOFGTMBBR4+GQxcHye0KrQZCAR9g7Q1bX1jc26rZXeSJMMTPQgZJIg9KnceE25oeGRPZDQ-gDWePQxDTsIqzF5CUmsKem48AA+0LqqvNyl5dJYvFRAA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript intentionally does not support this behavior, see [microsoft/TypeScript#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310).  The TypeScript team takes the position that when writing TypeScript code (as opposed to type-checking [JavaScript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#constructor-functions-are-equivalent-to-classes)) that if you want something to be `new`able you should be writing a `class`.

Furthermore, TypeScript doesn't model a constructor that `return`s something whose type is incompatible with the class, see [microsoft/TypeScript#38519](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38519).

Yes, it's true that these are possible in JavaScript, but part of the point of TypeScript is to be opinionated about which JavaScript behaviors are desirable to support, and which ones should be avoided.  See [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218)  Of course not everyone agrees *which* set of behaviors fall into each category, but it's clear from the above linked issues that the TypeScript team is not interested in supporting the sort of code you're writing.

---

If you want to do it anyway, you'll need to work around it somehow.  If you're only going to call it a few times, you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at each call.  But if you want something more general, you can abstract the type assertion into a helper function.

That is, you write a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function called, sya, `asNewable` that just returns its input at runtime, but we assert that the return type is a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) (as well as the original function type, why not):

```
function asNewable<A extends any[], R>(
    f: (...a: A) => R): { new(...a: A): R; (...a: A): R } {
    return f as any; 
}
```

And then

```
var autosense = asNewable(function (what: string) {
    if (what === 'a') {
        return new A();
    } else {
        return new B();
    }
});
/* var autosense: {
    (what: string): A | B;
    new (what: string): A | B;
} */
```

Now `autosense` is both a function and a constructor, according to the type system, and the following is allowed:

```
console.log(new autosense('a').val); // okay
```

Please note that since we've worked around the type system's restrictions, any problems you run into as a result are your responsibility.  For example:

```
const oops = asNewable(() => 3)
const whoops = new oops() // compiles okay, but
//  most likely a RUNTIME ERROR, oops is not a constructor
```

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) cannot be called with `new`.  There are possible ways to handle that, but that's out of scope for the question as asked.  The point is that you need to be careful when circumventing TypeScript this way, that the thing you've asserted is true in the use cases you care about.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQG5hALmgOwFcBbAIwFMAnAbhTWAHs8IAXCg4Z+igCgEpFaaNMwAWASwgA6TCGgBeaAEYaQgL5J1SUJBgAhAUJm5CpSirqMWbDlz4Ghw8VJnzoAJnOp1mzBWhgCTggyJjJXSAA5MgB3MBIQMm4AMwI8DjFGaG5okTBmXCsxPABzfmQhMSSsnLz5OQUAcjAGssEHCjJmAgo8fBi4Pk9oVWgyEGD7B2gOrp6+6OhdQbbvXhoAegAqDDA-AKCQ4NxytGzc-OhCkt5ceAAfRaG8frO8gtYi0tvoB90aEc26yQSBSaWYGV6kRicQSAB54GQAB7MEIAExgYDwAE8ANoAXQANNAAEoAPm4bSSuG4klpYFu-DkpJJN0Q8xpdIZuGJVCytMk9LgrOJw0m0063V6VUg-mxvPW62g0TCACsCCx-FBiGFRBIlWIQLJolwANb+ZjTVLgohkIkkQLQLH0AgNQ3QXLoMJgaAkMCo6CosBY6CVEPMBoYyEUCj0Bag9KMDTA5MMJj0BKSED0YrcZ4Lfb0YKhbhNFrSLBrFOWC30egABxgCihsXiiTsTOgAGZeFpq0qRLWG6489BBxA7AroAwiHWDWQYPQTUG7YEkJPALwbgFKdkkAVQiABUAJIAWQAotBT8TiQB5YlEschmB4egW72pqzsTgUIA)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```js
class A {
  val: number;
  constructor() {
    this.val = 1;
  }
}

class B {
  val: number;
  constructor() {
    this.val = 2;
  }
}

interface AutoSense {
  // Overload for 'a' argument
  (what: 'a'): A;
  // Overload for 'b' argument
  (what: 'b'): B;
  // Overload for 'a' argument
  new (what: 'a'): A;
  // Overload for 'b' argument
  new (what: 'b'): B;
  // fallback to B if it is not explicitly A or B
  (what: string): B;
  new (what: string): B;
};

const autosense: AutoSense = function (what) {
  if (what === 'a') {
    return new A();
  }
  return new B();
} as AutoSense;

const instanceA = autosense('a');
console.log(instanceA instanceof A); // Output: true
const instanceB = autosense('b');
console.log(instanceB instanceof B); // Output: true
const instanceB2 = autosense('c');
console.log(instanceB2 instanceof B); // Output: true

const newInstanceA = new autosense('a');
console.log(instanceA instanceof A); // Output: true
const newInstanceB = new autosense('b');
console.log(instanceB instanceof B); // Output: true
const newInstanceB2 = new autosense('c');
console.log(instanceB2 instanceof B); // Output: true
```

We basically define in the interface all the possible combinations and overload the function.