# Does using undefined as a property key guarantee the result will be undefined?

Tags: javascript

In a situation where an object property is retrieved through a variable i.e.:

```js
myObject[someField]
```

there is the possibility of `someField` (which is a string) to be `undefined` (the result of a potentially uninitialized string value). My experiments show that for all types of objects I can think of the result is `undefined` i.e.:

```js
anyObject[undefined] === undefined
```

Is this a well known behavior, something I can rely on? Can't seem to find something in [related documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) and my alternative would be to re-write the above as

```js
someField ? myObject[someField] : undefined;
```

but would really prefer the succinct way if there is a guarantee that `undefined` is returned whenever we try to access the property `undefined`.

Comment: `let a = { undefined: true }` and then `a[undefined]` is not that, but it's basically equivalent to `a.undefined`. All keys are "stringified".

Comment: The result of `String(undefined)` is the string value `"undefined"`. That's the actual name of the property your code is looking up when `someField` is `undefined`.

Comment: @tadman I guess that settles it. Didn't know you can add an undefined key ...

Comment: It's not an undefined key, it's a key with the label `"undefined"`.

Comment: But I don't have a label "undefined". I have the equivalent of `let someField; myObject[someField]` . Essentially I want to use a potentially uninitialized object to index a class instance

Comment: @LorahAttkins if you write `x[undefined]`, JS will coerce `undefined` to a string first, which is `"undefined"`.  See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#property_names) and maybe we can clean up these comments once we're all on the same page

Comment: I've untagged "TypeScript".  If you try this in TypeScript you will get an error that `Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)`, which you are apparently not asking about.  So either this isn't about TypeScript, or it is but the answer is "don't even try to do this because [it's not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, accessing `obj[undefined]` will not always return `undefined`. Like any value used as property name, `undefined` will get coerced to a string (unless it is a symbol), so it will actually access a property named "undefined". `obj[undefined]` is equivalent to `obj["undefined"]` or `obj.undefined`. It will return the property value if such a property exists, e.g. when `obj = {undefined: true};`.

You should indeed write

```
someField != null ? myObject[someField] : undefined;
```

if `someField: undefined | string`.

Comment: I wonder if `myObject.someField` should work (docs and local experiments seem to agree on that) but best to stick with the more idiomatic way , thanks

Comment: @LorahAttkins No, [that's something completely different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968406/1048572)