# In TypeScript, is there a shorthand for `index === undefined ? undefined : someArray[index]`?

Tags: typescript

Given the variables with types:

```
const someArray: number[];
const index: number | undefined;
```

is there a shorthand in TypeScript for the expression:

```
index === undefined ? undefined : someArray[index]
```

The above expression can become quite verbose especially if `index` itself is also an expression.

I understand the expression can be wrapped into a function, I'm just curious whether there's a builtin way to write this more concisely. For example, in JS, this can be simply: `someArray[index]`.

Comment: AFAIK TS only allows numbers as arguments to Array indexer. See [`readonly [n: number]: T` definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1294C5-L1294C29). I would extract a index variable if it is an expression, alternatively both `someArray[index as unknown as number]` and `someArray[index as any]` work, but to my eyes they are uglier than the ternary

Comment: ① It would be helpful if your code were a [mre] that people could paste into their IDEs. Could you declare `index` and `someArray`? ②  Those expressions are not equivalent unless you are 100% sure that `someArray` does not have a key named `"undefined"`, since that's what you're doing. See [this demonstration](https://tsplay.dev/N92LMm).  (more...)

Comment: (...continued) ③ TS doesn't let you index into a type with a random key, and `undefined` is also not a valid key. The ternary expression is safe and works; if you're worried about verbosity you can refactor to a function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMp0bN). ⊛ Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I clarified. I'm just curious whether there's some typescript builtin mechanism that I may have missed. Wrapping as a function is always a natural solution.

Comment: Did you see my ②?  `someArray[index]` is not equivalent to `index === undefined ? undefined : someArray[index]`.

Comment: @jcalz I see your point, the question has made a false assumption about JS. In other words, in JS we also need to use the ternary operator. Could you post the explanation? I'll accept it as an answer. The question itself is exactly one scenario where TS prevents some JS pitfalls!

Comment: I’ll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
index === undefined ? undefined : someArray[index]
```

is not equivalent to

```
someArray[index]
```

because if `index === undefined`, the former expression will definitely evaluate to `undefined`, while the latter is indexing into `someArray` with `undefined` as the [property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#property_names), which coerced `undefined` to the string `"undefined"`.  Thus `someArray[undefined]` is equivalent to `someArray.undefined`.  Will `someArray.undefined` exist?  Probably not. So in practice this is likely to be `undefined`, but it is technically possible:

```
const myArray: number[] = Object.assign([123], { undefined: "xyz" });
const index: number | undefined = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : undefined;
console.log(myArray[index] === undefined) // false
```

`myArray[index]` in the above example cannot be `undefined`.

---

Furthermore, even if they were equivalent, TypeScript adds a type system on top of JavaScript in order to add some type safety while still allowing for idiomatic JavaScript code.  Indexing into an object or array with a key that isn't of type `string` or `number` or `symbol` is really not idiomatic JavaScript. TypeScript takes the opinionated position that it is probably a mistake to use `undefined` as an index, because it is rarely what people actually intend to do. So even if it turned out that there were no edge cases to `someArray[index]`, it would still be considered illegal TypeScript. For more information, see [What does "all legal JavaScript is legal TypeScript" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750390/what-does-all-legal-javascript-is-legal-typescript-mean)

If you really want to write `someArray[index]` you can do so via [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and/or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to loosen type checking:

```
someArray[index as any]
```

If not, then `index === undefined ? undefined : someArray[index]` or a function that abstracts the operation is probably your best bet.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEC4ZgK5wBGApigNoC6MAvDAPKEBWxwUAdOhBAJYDmYACjIBGAEwBmCgBoYAbxh4wAE2IAzbmGJKcAIgAeCAF46YAXwCUAbgBQoSLA0q9OfEVIwAPguVqNWmjAAsuhQABZsGMogcALmMAA8MAAMbACsMAD8yTA4iirqmko2dhAgADbEbGUgvAKIqBgIZI7EejCc7WAIVNS93vl+SnEA9MMwquhlEMRAA)

Answer (score 0):

You've said the following:

> *"In JS, the above expression can be written as someArray[index]"*

But TypeScript is not different than JavaScript in this respect. That line of code has 100% identical behavior between TypeScript and JavaScript.

TypeScript, once compiled, produces normal JavaScript. If you were to inspect the output you will see its the same as your JavaScript code snippet (and thus behaves the same).

[Here is a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAJgUwB4wLwwCwCYDcAUKJLBCALbICCATrQIYCeAXDNLQgOYDaAuphg8A5AC9ktEMIA0MYeGQy5UAO5S+RQuSp1GTHghSoNQA) illustrating the point (you can observe the produced JavaScript in the side panel).

It's important to keep in mind that TypeScript does not produce different behavior than JavaScript because its not a distinct execution environment. TypeScript just produces normal JavaScript which executes just like any other JavaScript.  The only difference is that TypeScript gives you types and other syntax to help guide your code *before* it compiles out to JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In the question, `index` has type `number | undefined`, and thus a simple `someArray[index]` won't compile. I've updated the question.