# If I have an object or a string, how can I handle both?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function that can take a string or an object. If it gets an object, it uses the `name` property of the object, and if it gets a string it uses the string itself:

```
const foo = (bar: ({ name: string } | string)) => // take a string or object
    bar?.name ?? bar; // return the string or the name property
```

The problem is, TypeScript gives me this error:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type '(string | { name: string; })'.ts(2339)
```

If I did:

```
 foo('some string');
```

resulting in this:

```
 bar?.name ?? bar
```

becoming:

```
 'some string'?.name ?? 'some string'
```

...but even that is perfectly valid code! `'some string'?.name` simply returns `undefined`.

I understand I could write an entire second function called `isString`, and then I could do:

```
isString(bar) ? bar : bar.name;
```

But that's a lot of code for such a simple task. Do I have any other (shorter) options besides doing all that, or using `@ts-ignore`?

Comment: Just use `instanceof` instead of a new function?

Comment: You know your input's an _array_ type, right?! And yes `"a string".name` works in JS, but TS is there to prevent plenty of things that JS allows. See the various options for narrowing, including `instanceof` as suggest above, at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html.

Comment: although note that for primitives, you want `typeof` rather than `instanceof` (`instanceof String` will still flag an error, whereas `typeof` will not, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDeA7OBbCALgGdgAnAS2wHMBfAH1MpoG4AoNgMwFdsBjYBQD22KMAikAFABMEcQrDkpIASixsomqBU5RJoSEN2zEUNOagADJlWqW1mDlqi0oEADbFoj5874jiIXcIADp3IWoZORDcAhV2Z1o2JK5eAWFRcVIAJijEBXhEZQgHDS0dPRM4bWxSOH4IIygAZXJbUrLNVw8vdV8tf1qg0PDIqpj8EoStJKSgA)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oops, I meant to say `typeof`. You're right that's the correct option here.

Comment: But it *doesn't matter* what the type of the`bar` variable is :( If it's a string, the code works.  If it's an object, the code works.  There's no case TS is "protecting me from" here: I have two perfectly valid cases that can never, under any circumstances, result in an error.

Comment: TS lacks "exact"/"sealed" types ([ms/TS#12936](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)); TS says what props *do* appear but it doesn't track what props *do not* appear. This is useful for object type hierarchies & lets you extend an interface by adding props, but for primitives like string it's not great. By [ms/TS#33736](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33736) they won't make an exception for optional chaining. (more...)

Comment: (...continued) You could specify "a `string` without a defined `name` property" [as shown here](//tsplay.dev/wRev1W), but in general TS wants you to approach this differently, such as using a typeof check [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/NV5z5w). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a, it not, what am I missing?

Comment: Man that "`string` without a name" is some fugly code!  But here's the core thing I'm still not understanding (though I really appreciate the explanation): in Javascript I can do `"some string"?.anything` and it works.  I can do `123?.anything` and it works.  I can do `damnNearAnything?.anything` and it works.  TypeScript is supposed to be enforcing JS, not Ruby or some other language. When it says "you can't do X", it's supposed to be because the type of X doesn't support what you're doing ... but the type of `string` **DOES** support `?.anything`!  Even understanding the types, it's valid.

Comment: To put it another way, if I do `123.split()`, TS *justifiably* gets upset, because the `number` type can't be split.  If I try to treat some type (eg. a `number`) like some other type (eg. an `object`) it gets *justifiably* upset, because  the first type can't do what the second can.  The TS complaint *follows me doing something invalid with the type*.  In this case, there's never anything invalid: a TS programmer had to specifically add code to say "you can't do that" (even though you can).  I just want to grok why.

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching this wrong: TS isn't *just* about invalid code, it's also about warning you of bad practices, code smells, etc. ... stuff that *is* valid, but is probably a sign you're doing something wrong anyway.  Is this a case of TS considering`'aString'?.foo` to be a bad practice in some way?  If so, does TS have any documentation explaining why it's considered bad, so I can understand why they flag it?

Comment: TS doesn't know if `number` can be `split` or not. It complains because it doesn't know. If it *knew* that `number` *didn't* have a `split`, it might let you write `123.split` (which would be `undefined`) and then complain at `123.split()` (because `undefined` is not callable). `"xyz"?.name` is an error for the same reason; TS has no idea what might exist there. Its complaint isn't "oh no, that's `undefined`." It's "oh no, I have no idea what you're doing". TS can't possibly know what methods/props fail to exist without exact types, a missing feature as linked above.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to write up a full answer explaining how TS works, with links to documentation, but I *can't* guarantee that you'd be happy with it or agree with the TS language designers. So I'm a bit worried that I'll put in a bunch of effort into explaining as accurately as I can, and then end up having to keep supplementing with more information because it's not satisfying to you. How shall I proceed?

Comment: I don't need an explanation of how TS works, I just need an explanation of why it thinks `'foo'?.anything` is a problem.  It doesn't flag `1 + 2` or `someObject?.someProperty`.  All three are instances of valid JS, but only the first one gets flagged.  If you can explain why, I'd happily accept the answer (that's the entire point of me asking the question ...)

Comment: It doesn't let you access properties if it doesn't know they exist. It's considered to be a mistake. Maybe you're just asking why TS ever bothers to give errors in non-exception situations? Then this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41750390/2887218). If not, then I think we're at an impasse because I've explained it as much as I know how at this point. How should we move on from here?

Comment: The answer to the question you linked states "TypeScript may issue type warnings on code that it considers incorrect."  Neither you, nor anyone else, has explained the "incorrectness" of `'foo'?.anything`.  I have a very simple criteria for accepting an answer on this ticket: an explanation of why TS considers this *valid* code to be *incorrect* wins the checkmark.  Again from that answer "TypeScript's existence is predicated on the notion that some JavaScript code is not correct and you'd like to know about it." ... what does TS want me to know about that line?

Comment: Could you go through the exercise of re-reading my comments and trying to interpret them in the most charitable way possible, assuming that I have been, in good faith, attempting to answer your question? The relevant TS info is contained within. Assuming you still disagree, I've spelled it out as much as I can and at this point I'd only be repeating myself, which can't be fun for either of us. So I guess I can't help. Maybe someone else can come by and do it differently. I don't plan to interact further to reduce noise, and might come by later to remove my comments. Good luck!

Comment: You wrote "TS doesn't know if number can be split or not. It complains because it doesn't know.".  But you have never explained *why* it doesn't know.  It understands that my variable is a number.  The people who write TS can run `4?.foo` and see it works.  If TS didn't know my var's type, then what you say would make sense, *but it doesn't* because TS both knows the type, and *should* know it can be optionally chained.  If it doesn't, it should be because doing so is a "bad practice" TS is trying to protect me from ... but still no one has explained why TS considers it "bad".

Comment: It'd be sad if you removed your comments though; all that does is hurt future readers.

Comment: Neither TS nor you know what you might find at the `foo` property of a `number`. TS models types as open and extendible, to allow for future addition of properties or methods. Future JavaScript might put in `Number.prototype.foo = function(⋯)`. When you say `4?.foo` "works" I'm not sure what you mean by that. It won't have a runtime error, but that's not enough of a reason for TS not to complain. (it's the same as `(4).foo`, which it also complains about, nothing to do with optional chaining, right? `4` is non-nullish).  more...

Comment: ... The "warn on random prop indexing" is in the (hopelessly outdated) language spec [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#413-property-access), which is the closest I can imagine giving you a "why" answer, that isn't implicitly covered by the other question. I'm not in charge of TS so I can't answer "why" authoritatively more than that. Future readers are unlikely to benefit from an extended repetitive discussion where the participants disagree, in my opinion anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you say is valid code is valid JS, yes, but TS applies all kinds of rules that make valid JS invalid TS. That's what it's for. It's trying to prevent you from learning the hard way at runtime that `'some string'.name` will always be undefined.

Your options are:

- Tell TS to shut up, which can be done many ways but I would just use `@ts-ignore` to make it blatant that you're ignoring their advice.
- Do some kind of runtime type check. This uses solutions like `typeof`. This kind of defeats the purpose of compile time type checking in my opinion.
- Refactor to avoid this problem. This is what I would recommend, more below.

The fact that you're needing to check types at runtime is a sign to me that something is wrong here. As an option, consider a refactor so that you're not carrying around an array with values of multiple types in the first place, so this function doesn't even need to exist.

Comment: It's really more like it can take an array of strings or an array objects, not a mix ... but being able to take both is important (it would be less convenient to have to have two separate functions). But I still don't understand ... you say "It's trying to prevent you from learning the hard way " ... but again, I won't learn anything, hard or otherwise: *there is 100% nothing wrong with that code*! It will not get an error, even the in `undefined` case.   So, I don't understand why TS won't allow me to get an *expected* `undefined` by doing `'some string'.whatever`

Comment: No you're right, you're doing a check that will determine whether the arg is a string or an object, so in that sense the code is safe. TS doesn't know that though which is why I say it's 'trying'.  It's not capable of inferring in this case that what you're doing is safe. Because of that, I'm trying to give you the most idiomatic options.

I disagree on your first point. I would call for two different functions, one for an array of strings and a another for an array of objects, if you need both. A function should have one responsibility ideally; but you're giving it two different jobs here.

Comment: I truly don't think there's anything wrong with a JS function that can take two types of arrays.  Changing your *meaningful* code to make some linter (ie. TS) happy is the opposite of how such tools are supposed to work: they're supposed to produce better/more meaningful code, not force you to make your code needless complex to satisfy them.  That being said, thank you for explaining that TS can't infer the type, that sort of explains things ... but it doesn't explain *why* TS can't tell it's a string (or not) ... when you, me and the interpreter can all do so just fine.

Comment: TS does do a lot of type narrowing, but that's a pretty advanced language feature imo, which most compilers/interpreters can't even do as well as TS, so I cut them some slack. TS 5.4 is set to improve narrowing; you may look into whether newer versions can already do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `typeof` to check the passed value is a string. you can do something like this.

```
const foo = (bar: { name: string } | string): string => {
  if (typeof bar === 'string') {
     return bar; // If it's a string, return the string itself
  } else {
     return bar.name; // If it's an object, return the name property
  }
};

const result1 = foo('test string'); // Returns 'test string'
const result2 = foo({ name: 'John'}); //Returns the value of the name property
```